# Insert special characters like Omáš Klečková in Mysql database

Tags: mysql

When I use an insert that record in the database it saves with question mark. do I need to something with the field or the table or the insert query itself?

The table will have english + latin and mix characters

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName)
VALUES ('Omáš  Klečková');
```

[image]

Comment: Please add the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE Customers` to question. Basically, what is the character set of `CustomerName` field ?

Comment: which script you are using?

Comment: If you are using PHP script

$insert_data = mysql_real_escape_string($input_data);
Assuming that you have the data stored as $input_data